# Does not conform to the required signature for an invoke operation

Tags: wcf, domainservices

Ok I have a domain service class that only has 2 methods:

```
    [Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<CT1> GetActiveCT1(int ID)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.GetActiveCT1(ID).AsEnumerable<CT1>();
    }

    [Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<CT2> GetCT2(int ID)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.GetCT2(ID).AsEnumerable<CT2>();
    }
```

Both CT1 and CT2 is a complex type, with multiple int and string fields.

GetActiveCT1 and GetCT2 are both function imports based on stored procedure.

The problem is, method #2 GetCT2 always return an error about "does not conform to the required signature".  If I changed the [Invoke] to [Query] then it works, but method #1 doesn't have the same problem.

I am extremely puzzled why 2 complex type can behave so differently?